# Does $\int_{1}^{\infty}f'(x)G(x)dx$ converge?

Tags: calculus, integration

If $f(x), g(x) > 0$ on $(0, \infty)$, and $lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=lim_{x \to \infty}g(x)=0$ and $F, G$ antiderivatives of $f, g$. Then if $\int_{1}^{\infty}g'(x)F(x)dx$ converges, then does $\int_{1}^{\infty}f'(x)G(x)dx$ converges too? I think it's not converge. Because let $F(x)=-e^{-x}+C, G(x)=ln|x|+C$, then $f(x)=e^{-x}, g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. But this statement is now false.

Comment: Which statement is false? In your example the integrals converge.

Comment: Ok, then the calculation is wrong. But is $\int_{1}^{\infty}f'(x)G(x)dx$ converges true everytime?

Comment: Did you try integration by parts? And, what can you conclude about $F(x),G(x)$ as $x\to\infty$?